# How to overload for return types

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Really impossible to use return type overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481137/really-impossible-to-use-return-type-overloading)

Is there a way to take the same method and overload its return type? Like I did in the code below. I tried this but it says there is ambiguity between the two.

```
//supporting methods
private AutoResetEvent ReturnData = new AutoResetEvent(false);
public void PostMessage(string msg)
{ this.Message = msg; this.ReturnData.Set(); }
private string Message;
//a return value overload
public string GetMessage()
{
    this.ReturnData.WaitOne();
    return this.Message;
}
public byte[] GetMessage(){
    this.ReturnData.WaitOne();
    return encoder.GetBytes(Message);
}
```

Comment: No ................

Comment: No, just rename them slightly, e.g. GetMessageString etc

Comment: This is not possible I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload by return type in C#.

When something similar needs to be done in the .NET framework they usually change the method name to include the name of the return type.

**Example: [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf6bat53.aspx)**

```
double ReadDouble() { ... }
int ReadInt32() { ... }
```

**Example: [`SQLDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)**

```
double GetDouble(int i) { ... }
int GetInt32(int i) { ... }
etc...
```

In your case you could for example use `GetMessageString` and `GetMessageBytes`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extract from section 1.6.6 of the [C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx):

> "The signature of a method must be unique in the class in which the method is declared. The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the number of type parameters and the number, modifiers, and types of its parameters. The signature of a method does not include the return type."

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution works on method signatures.

Method signatures consist of the method names and the parameter types and numbers, but not the return type.

This means you can't overload a method by return type only.

In this case, a better design it to name the method according to the return type.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, the signature doesn't depend on the return type, so a solution could be:

```
public string GetMessageString()
{
    this.ReturnData.WaitOne();
    return this.Message;
}
public byte[] GetMessageBytes(){
    this.ReturnData.WaitOne();
    return encoder.GetBytes(Message);
}
```

Or you could solve the problem using a generic type:

```
public T GetMessage<T>()
{
    this.ReturnData.WaitOne();
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
       return this.Message;
    else if(typeof(T) == typeof(byte[]))
       return encoder.GetBytes(Message);

    return default(T);
}
```