# Why this method overloading anomaly?

Tags: c#, oop, overloading

I have seen numerous posts debating about overloading a method by changing its return type, but, the following program should ideally work fine, because the variable `i` of type integer can only hold integer values.

So, it should ideally call the function `int print(int a)` function and not even look at the function `float print(int a)` because it returns a float value, and in `main()`, I have used an integer variable to hold the value returned by the method, and an integer variable can never hold a float value ..

The following code demonstrates it →

```
class temp 
{
    public float print(int a) 
    {
        int l=12.55;
        return l;
    }

    public int print(int a) 
    {
        int p=5;
        return p;
    }
}

class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        temp t=new temp();
        int i=t.print(10);
        A.Read();
    }
}
```

In other scenario, where I do something like this →

```
class temp 
{
    public float print(int a) 
    {
        int l=12.55;
        return l;
    }

    public int print(int a) 
    {
        int p=5;
        return p;
    }
}

class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        temp t=new temp();
        float f=t.print(10);
        A.Read();
    }
}
```

Here, I accept that the compiler should generate an error, because it falls in a dilemma whether to call `public int(int a)` or `public float(int a)`, and because a variable of type float can holding both integer and float values ..

Comment: Please don't mix C# and Java as if they have the same behavior on this case.

Comment: @Luiggi: does Java allow overloads differing only in return type?

Comment: Java doesn't allow what you're asking. In order to make it work in Java, you should at least change one of the type of the parameters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza even java doesnt allow to overload methods by just changing the return types...

Comment: That still doesn't make this question applying for Java tag. By the way, there is a similar question related for Java: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2439782/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah.. you are right.. the way of calling methods was different in ur above linked example.. that's even a worst situation for the compiler..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Really impossible to use return type overloading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481137/really-impossible-to-use-return-type-overloading)

Comment: There is a definitive logic behind this, asked and answered many times on this site. It goes back to good old C : `double d = 5 / 2;` will make `d == 2.0`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That's mostly true, but there's a loophole: since Java 5, if you have an unfixed generic type parameter in a method (or, in Java 7, in a constructor invoked with the diamond operator) then you can have the same method return different types depending on context.  This only works at compile time, though: the erased type of all possible return values must be the same.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart ohh.. i am new to stackoverflow as u can verify my activities.. i dint knew that there is something like 'checking' the best answer.. i just googled and found out.. nevertheless, u answered to the point..

Comment: @SrinivasCheruku I understand, that's why I wanted to let you know. Welcome to the community.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no return-type overloading in c#. What if you had ignored the return value, or assigned it to an Object? Then which overload would be called? There are so many ambiguous scenarios, this would be nearly impossible to implement.

Comment: Indeed. `var i = t.print(10);` would need to be strongly typed, but to what?

Answer (score 5):

It's not because of that, it's because of other scenarios.

For example, you know when you call `Console.ReadLine()` just to wait for user input? (e.g. press enter to continue)? Well, you could do the same with your `print` method in this case. Which one should it call then? Should it call the `float` method? Should it call the `int` method? What happens when they use `var`? `dynamic`? Generics?

You could argue that it should compile in your case, because you're not using it like that. However, what if it's in a class library? What if it's called through reflection? You can't just spend half of the compile-time checking whether it will be called anywhere else, without the return type.

And also, it wouldn't be good practice. You couldn't easily tell them apart, so you could cause so many bugs with this.

So in short: it's **possible**, but it's so, so impractical it would never be considered as wanted by language designers<sup>[1]</sup>.

<sup>[1]</sup>: Interesting sidenote, MSIL allows it. So if you used `ildasm`, you **could** get return type overloading. Mainly because to call a function in it, you need to do this: `call MyReturnType MyFunc(MyType, MyOtherType)`

Comment: Looks like 3 concise lines beats 9 or more lines.

Comment: @SrinivasCheruku Just like to point out that it's possible in MSIL, which is what C# compiles to.

Comment: So wait, one had to mention *every* possible where the OP's thought is wrong to warrant an upvote?

Comment: Using `var` has no effect whatsoever, the *implicit* assignment is possible **because** there's no possible ambiguity with the return types of a function. And that's resolved *before* your C# is turned into MSIL for the CLR to consume, so there's no way return type overloading in MSIL could come from a csc-compiled C# app.

Answer (score 0):

say you had

```
int foo(int a){..}
double foo(int a) {...}
```

and then called

```
foo(1);
```

or var x = foo(1);

So which one did you mean to be called?

Trying to cope with the former would mean the compiler would have to figure out how the function was being called in the first case, the second is crossed fingers time.

Aside from that being PIA for the language designer what about the programmer? Seeing as it's easily corrected with fooInt, and FooFloat, why would anyone choose the extra level of complexity (not to mention performance with late binding) in favour of a more meaningful name?

The whole point of a strong and statically typed language is to remove this sort of ambiguity at compile time.