# Struggling to implement abstract property in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract

This all got a little trickier than I had intended. I'm using the `HistoricalReportWrapper` class because I retrieve my data through an API which has made it not realistic to have HistoricalReport implement `IReport` directly.

```
public abstract class CormantChart : Chart
{
    public abstract IReport Report { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class HistoricalChart : CormantChart
{
     public override HistoricalReportWrapper Report { get; protected set; }

     public HistoricalChart(HistoricalChartData chartData) : base(chartData)
     {
         Report = GetHistoricalReport(chartData.ReportID);
     }

     protected HistoricalReportWrapper GetHistoricalReport(int reportID)
     {
         return SessionRepository.Instance.HistoricalReports.Find(historicalReport => int.Equals(historicalReport.ID, reportID));
     }
}

public class HistoricalReportWrapper : IReport
{
    public HistoricalReport inner;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return inner.ID; }
        set { inner.ID = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return inner.Name; }
        set { inner.Name = value; }
    }

    public HistoricalReportWrapper(HistoricalReport obj)
    {
        inner = obj;
    }
}

public interface IReport
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is that when I am working inside of the `HistoricalChart` class I need to be able to access specific properties of the HistoricalReport. The rest of my program, however, only needs to have access to the HistoricalReport's ID and Name. As such, I would like to expose IReport's properties to the world, but then keep the details contained to the class.

As it stands, all the classes which inherit `HistoricalChart` generate a "does not implement inherited abstract member" as well as a warning on `HistoricalChart` indicating that I am hiding CormantChart's Report.

What's the proper way to declare this to achieve what I'd like?

Thanks

EDIT: Whoops, I missed an override. Now, when I try to override CormantChart Report I receive:

```
'CableSolve.Web.Dashboard.Charting.Historical_Charts.HistoricalChart.Report': type must be 'CableSolve.Web.Dashboard.IReport' to match overridden member 'CableSolve.Web.Dashboard.Charting.CormantChart.Report'    C
```

EDIT2: Taking a look at [C#: Overriding return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types) might be what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
 public HistoricalReportWrapper Report { get; protected set; }
```

is not an implementation of

```
 public abstract IReport Report { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: Err, sorry. I missed the override and added that, but still no go. HistoricalReportWrapper implements IReport, though -- is there a way to do what I intend?

Comment: Why is the property abstract in the first place? You say you only want to expose an `IReport` property to the world.

Comment: I marked it abstract because CormantChart is an abstract class and does not have the ability to set it itself. As such, I thought that the implementations would be handled by the derived classes? If I don't mark it as abstract what would that help?

Comment: I mean: 1) you can't change the type so the derived class needs just to implement an IReport property and then 2) why not wrap it up in the base class.