# C# Return different types?

Tags: c#, types

I have a method which returns different types of instances (classes):

```
public [What Here?] GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return radio; or return computer; or return hello //should be possible?!      
}
```

How can I do this and later work with the variables, e.g. `radio.Play()`, etc?

Do I need to use generics, and if so, how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types for a similar problem and a solution. I have to be honest, though, in that I think you have a design issue if you are doing this; if you have defined types then it should be possible to structure your code without this.

Comment: you can return `object` and then cast the result, or use a generic method

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: return type can be [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: This is one of the few areas I think Typescript is more powerful than C#. It would be nice to be able to say `public string|int GetSomeStringOrNumberValue()`, but of course this would open a huge can of worms as to how callers of the method would handle return values.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If there is no common base-type or interface, then `public object GetAnything() {...}` - but it would usually be preferable to have some kind of abstraction such as a common interface. For example if `Hello`, `Computer` and `Radio` all implemented `IFoo`, then it could return an `IFoo`.

Comment: But if Hello contains a `string hello` computer contains an `int number` and Radio contains a `System.Media.SoundPlayer mediaPlayer`. I can't access those from the IFoo

Comment: If you know what type to expect you can do something like `string value = (myFoo as Hello).hello` wherever you need your value.

Answer (score 61):

Here is how you might do it with generics:

```
public T GetAnything<T>()
{
   T t = //Code to create instance

   return t;
}
```

But you would have to know what type you wanted returned at design time.  And that would mean that you could just call a different method for each creation...

Answer (score 46):

use the dynamic keyword as return type.

```
 private dynamic getValuesD<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return "";
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

        int res = getValuesD<int>();
        string res1 = getValuesD<string>();
        double res2 = getValuesD<double>();
        bool res3 = getValuesD<bool>();
```

The `dynamic` keyword is preferable to use in this case instead of an object type because dynamic keyword keeps the underlying structure and data type so that you can directly inspect and view the value.

In object type, you have to cast the object to a specific data type to view the underlying value.

regards,

Abhijit

Comment: Why can you not return a Type T, as in:  private T getValuesD<T>()

Comment: If the incoming type is something other than int, string, or double (perhaps it's a class of some kind), then it returns false, a boolean, rather than the incoming type.  Consequently, in this case, one cannot express a return type of T.

Answer (score 18):

Marc's answer should be the correct one, but in .NET 4 you couldn't also go with dynamic type.

**This should be used only if you have no control over the classes you return and there are no common ancestors ( usually with interop ) and only if not using dynamic is a lot more painful then using(casting every object in every step :) ).**

Few blog post trying to explain when to use dynamic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/tags/dynamic/

```
public dynamic GetSomething()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio(); 
     return // anyobject

}
```

Comment: Actually, you can do just fine without the dynamic keyword. Just like my other comment states. This is not a scenario in which you use dynamic.

Comment: @Aidiakapi I know you could do it without dynamic, thats why I added the second line of my answer. Which is a good use of dynamic i think.For example you could have a similar problem using office interop dynamic can save you a lot of keystrokes :)

Comment: Dynamic has it's uses, but most people see it as a magical keyword, and overuse it. (Like in this example.) It should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: I'm glad you agree with that. I suspect he could wrap in all in an interface here.

Answer (score 15):

If you can make a abstract class for all the possibilities then that is highly recommended:

```
public Hardware GetAnything()
{
     Computer computer = new Computer();

     return computer;    
}

abstract Hardware {

}

class Computer : Hardware {

}
```

Or an interface:

```
interface IHardware {

}

class Computer : IHardware {

}
```

If it can be anything then you could consider using "object" as your return type, because every class derives from object.

```
public object GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();

     return hello;    
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To build on the answer by @RQDQ using generics, you can combine this with `Func<TResult>` (or some variation) and delegate responsibility to the caller:

```
public T GetAnything<T>(Func<T> createInstanceOfT)
{
    //do whatever

    return createInstanceOfT();
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Computer comp = GetAnything(() => new Computer());
Radio rad = GetAnything(() => new Radio());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just return an Object as all types are descended from Object.

```
public Object GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return radio; or return computer; or return hello //should be possible?!      
}
```

You could then cast to its relevant type:

```
Hello hello = (Hello)GetAnything();
```

If you didn't know what the type was going to be then you could use the `is` keyword.

```
Object obj = GetAnything();
if (obj is Hello) {
    // Do something
}
```

This being said I would be reluctant to write code like that. It would be much better to have an interface which is implemented by each of your classes.

```
public ISpeak GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return radio; or return computer; or return hello //should be possible?!      
}

interface ISpeak 
{
   void Speak();
}
```

and have each of your classes implement the interface:

```
public class Hello : ISpeak
{
    void Speak() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

You could then do something like:

```
GetAnything().Speak();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have the return type to be a superclass of the three classes (either defined by you or just use `object`). Then you can return any one of those objects, but you will need to cast it back to the correct type when getting the result. Like:

```
public object GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return radio; or return computer; or return hello //should be possible?!      
}
```

Then:

```
Hello hello = (Hello)getAnything();
```

Comment: This works really well, as long as you don't need to do any references back to a stored "object" inside that method. For example trying to return an already existing object without creating a new one might be a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

Let the method return a object from a common baseclass or interface.

```
public class TV:IMediaPlayer
{
   void Play(){};
}

public class Radio:IMediaPlayer
{
   void Play(){};
}

public interface IMediaPlayer
{
   void Play():
}

public class Test
{
  public void Main()
  {
     IMediaPlayer player = GetMediaPlayer();
     player.Play();
  }


  private IMediaPlayer GetMediaPlayer()
  {
     if(...)
        return new TV();
     else
        return new Radio();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rick's solution is the 'best' way to go in most cases. Sometimes when that's not available you want to use object as base type. And you could use the method like this:

```
public object GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return hello; // or computer or radio   
}
```

To use it, you will want to use the `as` operator, like this:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    object anything = GetAnything();
    var hello = anything as Hello;
    var computer = anything as Computer;
    var radio = anything as Radio;

    if (hello != null)
    {
        // GetAnything() returned a hello
    }
    else if (computer != null)
    {
        // GetAnything() returned a computer
    }
    else if (radio != null)
    {
        // GetAnything() returned a radio
    }
    else
    {
        // GetAnything() returned... well anything :D
    }
}
```

In your case you want to call a method play. So this'd seem more appropriate:

```
interface IPlayable
{
    void Play();
}

class Radio : IPlayable
{
    public void Play() { /* Play radio */ }
}

class Hello : IPlayable
{
    public void Play() { /* Say hello */ }
}

class Computer : IPlayable
{
    public void Play() { /* beep beep */ }
}

public IPlayable GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return hello; // or computer or radio   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options depending on why you want to return different types.

a) You can just return an object, and the caller can cast it (possibly after type checks) to what they want. This means of course, that you lose a lot of the advantages of static typing.

b) If the types returned all have a 'requirement' in common, you might be able to use [generics with constriants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

c) Create a common interface between all of the possible return types and then return the interface.

d) Switch to F# and use [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) and discriminated unions. (Sorry, slightly tongue in check there!)

Comment: Lol, or you could go to C++ and use `void*` >.<, I doubt he wants to use any other programming language than what he asked.

Comment: That's why it's option d. Having said that, I've several projects that have a mixed F#/C# code base; each of the languages has it's own strong points.

Comment: I agree, just like C++/CLI does, which can also be shared in projects. Nevertheless I think it's quite unrelated to the question. (Don't get me wrong, I like F#, it's great for very specific cases.)

Answer (score 1):

Defining a single type for all is not always possible. Even if when you can, the implementation is rarely easy. I prefer to use `out` parameters. The only caveat is that you need to know all the return types in advanced:

```
public void GetAnything(out Hello h, out Computer c, out Radio r)
{
     /// I suggest to:
     h = null;
     c = null;
     r = null; 
     // first, 

     // Then do whatever you have to do:
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();
}
```

The return type can be a `void`, or something else, like `bool` an `int` or a predefined `enum` which can help you check for exceptions or different cases wherever the method is used.

Answer (score 1):

My post here is strictly related to **Blazor** v5 but should work in 3.x as well. Additionally, I'm using these methods with bootstrap 4.5 and 5.0 beta 1 but you could easily adapt it to use style's instead of classes or use your own classes.

To those recommending dynamic, I thank you. The dynamic type seems like it can be very valuable when used correctly. Most of the time you'll probably use an interface but this wasn't plausible for me. I went ahead and updated my project with a dynamic return type and it's working great while being the quickest, cleanest solution.

I previously added the following extension methods to boolean types to help me avoid long ternary operators in razor page code.
Here are the 3 main extension methods I use to accomplish it:

```
public static T Then<T>(this bool value, T result) => value ? result : default;    
public static T Then<T>(this bool value, T thenResult, T elseResult) => value ? thenResult : elseResult;
public static T Else<T>(this bool value, T result) => !value ? result : default;
```

The following are examples of that implementation:

```
<div class="@Hidden.Then("d-none")">
    Hidden content...
</div>
```

**Note**: ErrorOrWarning would hide the content if there was no error/warning so I could default it to yellow/italic but this is an example so please use your imagination:

```
<div class="@ErrorOrWarning.Else("d-none")" style="@Error.Then("color:red;font-weight:bold;","color:yellow;font-style:italic;")">
    Error/Warning content...
</div>
```

This is the typical implementation without the extension methods. It's common to see this technique in Blazor guides/tutorials/videos online. There are cleaner ways to handle it but this is the basic idea:

```
<div class="@(ErrorOrWarning ? "" : "d-none")" style="@(Error ? "color:red;font-weight:bold;" : "color:yellow;font-style:italic;")">
    Error/Warning content...
</div>
```

While this might not seem like too big a difference, if you have a lot of dynamic content/styles driving your page, it can get really messy. With those 3 lines of code you can enhance the readability and cleanliness and it really does reduce risk of typos. Adding two more extension methods, you can reduce the risk even further *Note: Again, this is using bootstrap class "d-none" for the style "display:none!important" but you could just as easily replace with your own usage*:

```
public static string ThenShow(this bool value) => value ? "" : "d-none";
public static string ThenHide(this bool value) => value ? "d-none" : "";
```

The limitation I previously faced was when using the overloaded **Then(thenResult, elseResult)**, each of the parameters must be of the same type. 99% of the time this is fine. Actually, another 0.5% of the time it's still okay because you can probably solve it quickly with a .ToString() or an explicit cast.

What I ran into, and what took me to this post was:
I have a control you can imagine as a button. There is an Enum property allowing the user to select an icon to display. The selected Enum dynamically populates a readonly **MarkupString** property. As an alternative option, they can use the ChildContent (or IconContent in my example) of type **RenderFragment**. This will let them manually add anything they want (maybe an iFrame to stackoverflow haha) but my intention is for them to add style, most likely in the form of an icon.

I know I can cast/convert one to the other however my existing extension method is so clean and simple, it would be great to be able to use pass the **MarkupString** and **RenderFragment** together as parameters, conditionally output to the razor page. So, thanks to this post, I changed my ***Then(thenResult, elseResult)*** extension methods to use unique generic parameter types and return a dynamic type like so:

```
public static dynamic Then<T,E>(this bool value, T thenResult, E elseResult) => value ? thenResult : elseResult;
```

Now in my razor page I have a very simple line for the icon output. Note: IconContent is a **RenderFragment** and IconMarkup is a **MarkupString**.

```
@((@IconContent == null).Then(IconMarkup, IconContent))
```

And because I love extension methods and I'm typing this up, I took it a step further with another extension method:

```
public static bool IsNull(this RenderFragment value) => value == null;
```

Which enables the extremely clean and simple:

```
@IconContent.IsNull().Then(IconMarkup, IconContent)
```

Here's the extra extension method I mentioned above which converts a string to a MarkupString. It might be overkill but I like it.

```
public static MarkupString ToMarkup(this string value) => (MarkupString)value;
```

Let me know if you have a better recommendation or if you think I'm doing something wrong. I'm sure this post makes it seem like I overuse extension methods but I really don't. I keep their use limited to outcomes such as I've outlined in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use external class, set the properties types as you wish, then use it in your function.

```
public class MultipleOpjects
{
    private List<string> _ObjectOne;
    public List<string> ObjectOne {
        get { return _ObjectOne; }
        set { _ObjectOne = value; }
    }
    private List<object> _ObjectTwo;
    public List<object> ObjectTwo {
        get { return _ObjectTwo; }
        set { _ObjectTwo = value; }
    }
    private object _ObjectThree;
    public object ObjectThree {
        get { return _ObjectThree; }
        set { _ObjectThree = value; }
    }
}
public MultipleOpjects GetAnything()
{
    MultipleOpjects Vrble = new MultipleOpjects();
    Vrble.ObjectOne  = SomeThing1;
    Vrble.ObjectTwo = SomeThing2;
    Vrble.ObjectThree = SomeThing3;

    return Vrble;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a sample using Generic Types.

```
public T GetAnything<T>() where T : class, new()
    => new T();
```

And you'll use this method calling this way:

```
var hello = GetAnything<Hello>();
```

In this case, you can use an interface to specify a type to pass as parameter.

```
public T GetAnything<T>() where T : ISomeInterface, new()
    => new T();
```

You must have a parameterless construtor in each class to use new() constraint.

Follow the full sample:

```
internal sealed class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetAnything<Hello>().Play();
        GetAnything<Radio>().Play();
        GetAnything<Computer>().Play();
    }

    private static T GetAnything<T>() where T : ISomeInterface, new()
        => new T();
}

internal interface ISomeInterface
{
    void Play();
}

internal sealed class Hello : ISomeInterface
{
    // parameterless constructor.
    public Hello() { }
    public void Play() => Console.WriteLine("Saying hello!");
}

internal sealed class Radio : ISomeInterface
{
    // parameterless constructor.
    public Radio() { }
    public void Play() => Console.WriteLine("Playing radio!");
}

internal sealed class Computer : ISomeInterface
{
    // parameterless constructor.
    public Computer() { }
    public void Play() => Console.WriteLine("Playing from computer!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in other answers before, it is preferable to have some kind of abstraction as a common interace or abstract base class.

In some cases it is not possible or not appropiate to introduce such abstraction.
As alternative some answers suggests returning an `object` and cast it back to the original type: `public object GetAnything() {...}`.

The only "problem" with that solution is, that the caller have to know of what possible type the `object` can be.
To avoid that problem we can introduce an object that provides an "interface" that directly communicates the possible object types to the caller.

The following code uses a `struct` to avoid additional heap allocation. The `DynamicObject` just contains one `object` and the needed methods.
You may want to add null checks in the `DynamicObject` constructors.

```
// Usage of DynamicObject.
public void ExampleUsage()
{
    DynamicObject dynamicObject = GetAnything();
    if (dynamicObject.TryGetRadio(out Radio radio))
        radio.Play();
    else
        ; // ...
}

public DynamicObject GetAnything()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    switch (rnd.Next(0, 3))
    {
        case 0:
            return new DynamicObject(new Hello());
        case 1:
            return new DynamicObject(new Computer());
        case 2:
            return new DynamicObject(new Radio());
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException(); // Not possible.
    }
}

// Implementation of DynamicObject.
public struct DynamicObject
{
    private readonly object _value;

    public DynamicObject(Hello hello) => _value = hello;

    public DynamicObject(Computer computer) => _value = computer;

    public DynamicObject(Radio radio) => _value = radio;

    public bool TryGetHello(out Hello hello) => TryGetAsConcreteObject(out hello);

    public bool TryGetComputer(out Computer computer) => TryGetAsConcreteObject(out computer);

    public bool TryGetRadio(out Radio radio) => TryGetAsConcreteObject(out radio);

    private bool TryGetAsConcreteObject<T>(out T value)
    {
        if (_value is T concreteObject)
        {
            value = concreteObject;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an object then put all your data in it. Return that object. Cast the object as an array (Array)yourObject then cast the values of the array as an integer or what you want.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        object data = MyMethod();
        Array dataarray = (Array)data;
        string astring = (string) dataarray.GetValue(0);
        int aninteger = (int)dataarray.GetValue(1);
        Console.WriteLine(astring);
        Console.WriteLine(aninteger);
    }

    static object MyMethod()
    {   
        /// create an object array

        object[] myarray = new object[2];

        /// put your values in it (remeber their order to cast them right later)

        myarray[0] = "any string";
        myarray[1] = 3;
        
        /// convert the object array to a singel object
        
        object _myarray = (object) myarray;
        return _myarray;
    }

}
```

This method of retuning multipile values as one object is very helpful for building a program with ParameterizedThreadStart.
(I'm sorry for bad my explination but the code works and everyone should be able to understand it)

Answer (score -1):

The only viable answers here (aside from implementing a shared interface) is either to use Tuple in the following fashion:

```
public static (int?, string?) ReturnMultiple(int number)
    {
        return number switch
        {
            10 => (10, null),
            _ => (null, "Not ten at all!"),
        };
    }
```

But this is undoubtedly an error-prone solution.

Or you may want to try this Kotlin-like approach to algebraic datatypes.

```
namespace Options
{
    public abstract record IOption
    {
        public static void ConsumeOptions(IOption option)
        {
            string result = option switch
            {
                StringOption x => $"String {x.Value}",
                IntegerOption x => $"Integer {x.Value}",
                _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented for {option.GetType()}!")
            };
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static IOption CreateOption(int value) => new IntegerOption(value);

        public static IOption CreateOption(string value) => new StringOption(value);
    }

    public sealed record StringOption(string Value) : IOption;
    public sealed record IntegerOption(int Value) : IOption;
    // Intentionally forgotten option throwing an exception
    public sealed record CharOption(char Value) : IOption;
}
```

This is a bit safer way to do things IMHO, even though is a far cry from Kotlin's ADTs.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html

It should be noted that the Decide method is placed in the abstract record for the sake of convenience. It can be used anywhere.

Contrary to Kotlin's approach, there is no guarantee of further reimplementing IOption abstract record, so the last switch branch will fail as soon as a new unexpected implementation appears.

Similarly to implementing a shared interface, even this approach using an abstract class is not exactly bulletproof. One can easily omit the implementation of one or more possible options, yet this approach enables the elegant processing of passed arguments.

The resulting options are sealed to prevent creating their children, but since the abstract class is public, there is no guarantee whatsoever. Anyone can easily create another option class and end up with the unimplemented exception.

Answer (score -3):

May be you need "dynamic" type?

```
public dynamic GetAnything()
{
     Hello hello = new Hello();
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Radio radio = new Radio();

     return /*what boject you needed*/ ;`enter code here`   
}
```

Comment: This is **not** what dynamic is a correct usage for. Dynamic is just a fancy wrapper around reflection, and is used for truly dynamic objects. Not for simple object oriented scenarios.