# Method returning multiple data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, return-value, return-type

Currently I'm working on a project where it has an admin side and client side.

The admin side uses `DirectResult` to execute any admin related actions where as the client uses `JsonResult` to render the page, and I want to use the same `Controllers`. Methods to return either `DirectResult` or `JsonResult` depending on the request.

For instance:

- `Admin`  : `Class1.Method()` --> should return `DirectResult`
- `Client` : `Class1.Method()` --> should return `JsonResult`,

and both results are requested using `Ajax` requests.

Comment: Ever heard of generics? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Do DirectResult or JsonResult have anything in common programatically speaking? It feels to me that Method() should be on a class representing the Admin or Client but this is very hard to say without knowing your design.

Comment: Have they a common interface or base class?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this due to limitations of C#.
Every method in a class C# must have a unique method signature, but return types are not counted in the signature.

Consider creating the Ajax method with a different name (as this is the one that is not visible to your clients, usually).

Constraints (generics) are [not part of the method signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx), so unless you were passing different arguments to your methods, it would have the same result as just naming them the same w/ different return types.

EDIT: I misunderstood. If DirectResult and JsonResult both inherit from the same base type, you can just return either of those, casted to the base type, in the response.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in this question: [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986975/c-sharp-return-different-types). 
Another way to do it without returning general object is to implement same ancestor for both return types and set it as return type. 
Or return [Tuple](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple) with nulls.