# dotnet return 1 of 2 types

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple method setup to create an entry and if it's successful, return the created entry. If it wasn't return the ValidationError.

```
public async Task<MyNewEntry> CreateEntry(MyUser user, MyEntryRequest entry)
```

This works great if the entry was valid. But, I want to return the ValidationError if the validation failed.

I tried doing this:

```
public async Task<MyNewEntry | ValidationError> CreateEntry(MyUser user, MyEntryRequest entry)
```

But then it doesn't compile. How do I construct this method so that it's capable of returning either `MyNewEntry` or `ValidationError`

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything built-in. You could wrap them in an [Either](https://mikhail.io/2016/01/validation-with-either-data-type-in-csharp/) structure (like [Scala has](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html)), or e.g. wrap the validation error in an exception, or return one as an out param and the other one null if set, but I'm not sure any of these are super clean.

Comment: Returning two different types is generally a bad idea.  You could simply setup a "valid" flag in your MyNewEntry class that indicates success or failure.

Comment: Yea, I was trying to avoid modifying the types as they are third party. I think I'll just make a wrapper class that knows how to handle it.

Comment: Use a`Tuple`? A parent class? Really sounds like you should be throwing an exception though. Validation fails aren’t something you can resolve in compile time

Comment: This would be exception driven design, and given the impact that exceptions have on the application, this should be avoided under all circumstances.
Avoid throwing exceptions, when you know what can happen. Validation-Result, no matter what kind, are not exceptions.

Comment: I'd second Caius Jard, throw an exception

Comment: Opinions are all valid. But, in this case it's ultimately an HttpRequest and if there is a validation error, I just want the validation error so I can show that to the user and have them correct the entry until it's valid.'

Comment: There are plenty options in existing question about returning different types, in particular accepted answer is roughly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376993/477420.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you could use a Result-Type, wich consists of a Property "bool Success" and a Error as well as a Entry property of which always only one is filled with a value, depending on the success of your method.

```
public class CreateEntryResult
{
    public bool Success {get;set;}
    public MyNewEntry Entry {get;set;}
    public ValdidationError Error {get;set;}
}
```

To save some memory (you would create an additional object on every result), you may also return a struct. Just replace the "class" keyword in my code with "struct". The contained references will then be passed as values, and you dont have to think about any impact to the garbage collection.

Another way of doing this, which i haven't seen alot in recent years is the "Try" pattern, where you return a result type (normally a bool) and use out-parameters to return your values.
Im not sure how out-parameters work together with async.

```
bool TryCreateEntry(..., out MyNewEntry entry, out ValidationError error)
```