# c# generics interface solution

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a interface named `Man`.
In this interface I have the method `getList()` that returns a list of type T (dependent by class that implements the interface).
I have 3 classes that implement `Man`: `small`, `normal`, and `big`.
Every class has the method `getList()` thart returns a list of `small` or a list of `normal` or a list of `big`.

```
interface Man<T>{
  List<T>getList();
}

class small : Man<small>{
  List<small> getList(){
    return new List<small>(); 
  }
}

class normal : Man<normal>{
  List<normal> getList(){
    return new List<normal>(); 
  }
}

class big : Man<big>{
  List<big> getList(){
    return new List<big>(); 
  }
}
```

Now I have the class: `Home`  that contains a parameter `bed` that's an instance of `Man`.
`Bed` can be of various types: `small`, `normal`, `big`. How can I declare the type parameter for `bed`?

```
class Home{
  Man bed<> // what i must insert between '<' and '>'??
}
```

Comment: Do `small`, `normal`, and `big` share a common base class, if so, I'd recommend adding a [where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8(v=vs.80).aspx) to your type definition, and if not, you may want to think about giving them a base class so you can, cause it seems that you are limiting your type to a size.

Comment: i tried to do:
class Home<T> where T: small,normal,big{
Man bed<T>
}
but i have error :(

Comment: Take a look at this solution to a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types/13717025#13717025 .

Comment: @EnnioPastore You need to specify a common base class, you can't list classes you want to limit it to, you should probably have the constraint on both the interface and you `Home` class i.e.:  public interface IMan<T> where T : Size{ }   public class Home<T> where T : Size { }   public abstract class Size { // size objects inherit this }

Comment: @EnnioPastore interfaces can also be used in the where clause, the type constraint needs to be something in common that the classes either inherit or implement.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make `Home` generic, as well:

```
class Home<T> 
{
    Man<T> bed;
```

---

Edit in response to comments:

If you do not know what type of "Man" will exist, another option would be to make your generic class implement a non-generic interface:

```
public interface IBed { // bed related things here

public class Man<T> : IBed
{
   // Man + Bed related stuff...

class Home
{
     IBed bed; // Use the interface
```

You can then develop against the shared contract defined by the interface, and allow any type of `IBed` to be used in the `Home`.

---

On an unrelated side note, I'd recommend using better naming schemes here - the names don't make a lot of sense... Why is a "Man" named "bed"?  You might also want to review the standard [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: the parameter bed must change type.. one time can be "small", another time "normal", another time "big".. I don't know what type it can become..

Comment: @EnnioPastore Have you considered making an `IBed` interface, and making `Man<T>` implement it?  You could then use hte interface.

Comment: IMHO using a method in the Man class with a parameter of type IBed might be better than a Man class implementing IBed methods For eg: InstanceOfMan.CheckBedSuitablity(InstanceOfIBed)

Comment: @SuryaPratap Yes, I agree - but was trying to match the OP's requirements as written.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly pin down what you are asking so I am going to infer you are having trouble figuring out how to set a parameter 'bed size' for a house.

This is probably better solved by using an Enum. That way you can have a single object that describes the size of the bed.

```
public interface IBed
{
    BedSize BedSize { get; set; }
}

public enum BedSize
{
   Small,
   Medium,
   Large
}

public class House : IBed
{
  public BedSize BedSize { get; set; }
}
```

This reduces the complexity of determining the size of the bed later so you won't have to do reflection or something nasty like that.

Comment: If you need to just use a class and an interface why not do 'just that'.