# Overriding methods with derived type

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I need the following inheritance:

```cs
public class Persistent
{
    public virtual Persistent Clone() { ... }
}

public class Animal : Persistent
{
    public override Animal Clone() { ... }
}
```

This can be implemented using a generic class:

```cs
public class Persistent<T>
{
    public virtual T Clone() { ... }
}

public class Animal : Persistent<Animal>
{
    public override Animal Clone() { ... }
}
```

However inheriting further from Animal does not work:

```cs
public class Pet : Animal
{
    public override Pet Clone() // return type is Animal
}
```

Obviously Pet should derive from Persistent<Pet> for this to work but I need classic inheritance. Unfortunately C# supports neither multiple inheritance nor mixins. Is there any workaround?

Comment: What's the usefulness of `Persistent<T>` here? Not clear.

Comment: you can use method hiding feature of C#. For this you don't even need to override the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types

Comment: You can still use the Animal instead of Pet in overrided method, though you return an instance of Pet. The only thing is you have to typecast it back to Pet at the calling place.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco: I believe it is not a duplicate, as the reference does not extend beyond immediate descendants of the generic class, I have not scrutinized SO thoroughly though.

Comment: @KrishnaSarma: Yes, that's what I am trying to avoid - double casting and type unsafety.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't mind using a different approach, if it exists. By the way, the current one is also necessitated by a third-party library that is based on generics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution **without generics**:

```
public class Persistent
{
    protected virtual object CloneOverride()
    {
        return new Persistent();
    }

    public Persistent Clone()
    {
        return (Persistent)CloneOverride();
    }
}

public class Animal : Persistent
{
    protected override object CloneOverride()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }

    public new Animal Clone()
    {
        return (Animal)CloneOverride();
    }
}

public class Pet : Animal
{
    protected override object CloneOverride()
    {
        return new Pet();
    }

    public new Pet Clone()
    {
        return (Pet)CloneOverride();
    }
}
```

The good point is that you hide ancestors `Clone()` methods as expected, and the pattern is always the same.

The drawback is that it's easy to make a mistake because `CloneOverride()` is not type safe.

(see also my other answer with generics)

Comment: In your example, object type could be replaced with Persistent to be more type safe. Regardless, the new modifier destroys polymorphism, e.g. if [this.]Clone() was called from within Persistent's virtual method, that would always call Persistent's Clone().

Comment: EDIT: Clone() in fact may have more logic. Here I'm trying to avoid the casting, otherwise would use Persistent return type in overrides.

Answer (score 0):

With method hiding

```
    public class Persistent
    {
        public Persistent Clone() { ... }
    }

    public class Animal : Persistent
    {
        public new Animal Clone() { ... }
    }
```

From your code I am assuming you are doing it for cloning. So you can create a cloner,

```
public class Persistent
{
    public virtual Dictionary<string, object> GetCloneDictionary()
    {
        return //dictionary containning clonning values.
    }
    public void SetValues( Dictionary<string, object> objects)
    {
       //set values from dictionary
    }

}

public class Animal : Persistent
{
    public override Dictionary<string, object> GetCloneDictionary()
    {
        return //dictionary containning clonning values.
    }
    public override void SetValues( Dictionary<string, object> objects)
    {

    }
}

public class Animal2 : Animal
{
    public override Dictionary<string, object> GetCloneDictionary()
    {
        return //dictionary containning clonning values.
    }
    public override void SetValues( Dictionary<string, object> objects)
    {

    }
}


public class PersistentClonner<T> where T : Persistent
{
    public virtual T Clone(T obj)
    {
        obj.GetCloneDictionary();
        //create new and set values
        return //new clone
    }
}

public class AnimalClonner : PersistentClonner<Animal>
{
    public override Animal Clone(Animal obj)
    {
        obj.GetCloneDictionary();
        //create new and set values
        return //new clone
    }
}
```

Comment: `((Persistent)myAnimal).Clone()` and you get a... `Persistent`, not `Animal`

Comment: No, the Clone method is just an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works the way you want it to, although I'd ask why Persistent needs to be a class and not an interface.

```
public class Persistent
{
    public virtual Persistent Clone() { return null; }
}

public class Animal : Persistent<Animal>
{
    public override Animal Clone() { return null; }
}

public class Persistent<T>
{
    public virtual T Clone() { return default(T); }
}

public class Animal : Persistent<Animal>
{
    public override Animal Clone() { return null; }
}

public class Pet : Animal
{
    public new Pet Clone()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit irregular, as Pet is not as consistent as Animal in terms of T specific methods. I need a class, not an interface, to implement some basic logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution **with generics**:

```
public abstract class Persistent<T>
{
    protected abstract T CloneOverride();

    public T Clone()
    {
        return CloneOverride();
    }
}

public class Animal : Persistent<Animal>
{
    protected override Animal CloneOverride()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }

    public new Animal Clone()
    {
        return CloneOverride();
    }
}

public class Pet : Persistent<Pet>
{
    protected override Pet CloneOverride()
    {
        return new Pet();
    }

    public new Pet Clone()
    {
        return CloneOverride();
    }
}
```

(see also my other answer without generics)

Comment: Under the classic inheritance, I mean that Pet should inherit Animal's behavior by default.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
public class Persistent
{
    public virtual Persistent Clone()
    {
        return new Persistent();
    }
}

public class Animal : Persistent
{
    public new Animal Clone()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }
}

public class Pet : Animal
{

}

public class Wild : Animal
{
    public new Wild Clone()
    {
        return new Wild();
    }
}

private static void Test()
{
    var p = new Persistent().Clone();
    Console.WriteLine("Type of p: {0}", p);

    var a = new Animal().Clone();
    Console.WriteLine("Type of a: {0}", a);

    var t = new Pet().Clone();
    Console.WriteLine("Type of t: {0}", t);

    var w = new Wild().Clone();
    Console.WriteLine("Type of w: {0}", w);
}
```

Comment: This does work when Clone() is called directly but not when from within a virtual method of any of the classes.

Comment: Thanks for the input Herman. Let me understand this better. Please provide a example scenario like say in the above code if you call Pet.Clone() you want Pet object to be returned?

Comment: I want Persistent instances to have methods for storing, cloning, serializing, etc. In fact, Persistent class has too many methods and too many descendants to override in such a manner. It is tedious and also violates the DRY principle, as the implementation across the hierarchy is basically identical except for argument and return types. I could use base class everywhere, like in Object.Equals(), but wonder if there is a better way to avoid double casting.