# Avoid copying & pasting of almost generic code in subclasses

Tags: c#, inheritance, subclass

I currently have a class which encapsulates a list of typed objects and implements some interfaces like IEnumerable. I need a second class with additional, slightly different properties. So I will be creating a base class A and derive new class B and new class C from A.

However I have code (e.g like code for .Find using Delegates) which is almost the same in B and C. The only difference is that the code in B searches the private list of typed objects (let's say Person) and the code in C searches a private list of different objects (let's say Animal):

```
    private static bool Find(Person xx)
    {
        if (xx.Id == someID)
        {
            return true;
        }
    else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As I want to avoid copying/pasting, my question is: What is a good strategy to avoid something like that?

The only way I imagined was to declare a list of generic objects in A and point the methods in A to that. In B and C I would then not have any code, however I lose all benefits of a typed list.

Comment: Make your class A generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I would see if I could use generics when coding class A

```
public class cA<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _myPrivateData

    public bool Find(args)
    {
        // Do stuff with _myPrivateData
    }
}

public class cB : cA<TheTypeIWant>
{
    // more stuff here if needed
}
```

2) You can use the property override feature + the use of the `protected` access modifier to do the following:

```
public class cA
{
    protected IEnumerable<Object> MyData { get; set; }

    public bool Find(args)
    {
        // Do stuff with MyData
    }
}

public class cB : cA
{
    protected new IEnumerable<MyOtherDataType> MyData { get; set; }
}
```

Of course `MyOtherDataType` has to inherit from the base type used for this approach to be possible. I would really not recommend this approach though. Option 1 is much better and cleaner.

Here's a few references that may prove to be useful:

- http://peisker.net/dotnet/covariance.htm
- [C#: Overriding return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types)

Comment: If your items can have Ids, Paul D'Ambra's example of using the repository pattern can be interesting and a very good solution too.

Comment: I looked into generics and it was the easiest answer. However I'll also try to get myself into the repository pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to have an interface like `ICanBeFoundById`

```
public interface ICanBeFoundById 
{
  int Id {get;}
}
```

then Person and Animal can both inherit from that and you can do something like

```
public static class FindExtensions
{
  public static bool Find(this IEnumerable<ICanBeFoundById> xs, int someID)
  {
    return xs.Any(x=>x.Id == someID)
  }
}
```

Warning: I haven't even checked if this compiles :)

Of course you could have some

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<ICanBeFoundById>
{
  private IEnumerable<ICanBeFoundById> _xs;

  public static bool Find(int someID)
  {
    return xs.Any(x=>x.Id == someID)
  }
}
```

if you don't want to have a static extension.

Comment: It should compile and work with no issue provided you add "using System.Linq" to the code

Comment: i would change `private IEnumerable<ICanBeFoundById> _xs;` to be a protected item so that he can new it up and force the type in his subclasses allowing him to keep the benefits of a typed list [as per #2 in my answer] (I don't think it necessarily needs to be a property, though I've never tried on a regular field)

Comment: Yep, mine is very much example code... it all really depends how things are used. Force of habit to type protected - I tend to hide things until they need to be more open