# how to override a method of Microsoft Identity?

Tags: c#, .net

I am newbie in C# and .Net
I am using a getter of SignInManager in one of my controllers like this:

```
public CustomSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<CustomSignInManager >();
    }
}
```

and the CustomSignInManager class is like this:

```
public class OnlineSmSignInManager : SignInManager<User, int>
{
    public OnlineSmSignInManager(OnlineSmUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    { }
}
```

there is a method in Identity's SignInManager class like this:

```
public virtual async Task<token> SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(string provider)
{
    TKey userId = await this.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync().WithCurrentCulture<TKey>();
    if ((object) userId == null)
        return false;

    string token = await this.UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(userId, provider).WithCurrentCulture<string>();
    IdentityResult identityResult = await this.UserManager.NotifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(userId, provider, token).WithCurrentCulture<IdentityResult>();
    return token;
}
```

how can I override it to be like this:

Comment: You can't change the return type of a method that you override, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# virtual members can be overriden by replacing the word virtual in the derived class:

```
public override async Task<bool> SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(string provider)
{
  TKey userId = await this.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync().WithCurrentCulture<TKey>();
  if ((object) userId == null)
    return false;
  string token = await this.UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(userId, provider).WithCurrentCulture<string>();
  IdentityResult identityResult = await this.UserManager.NotifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(userId, provider, token).WithCurrentCulture<IdentityResult>();
  return true;
}
```

That goes in your CustomSignInManager class.

Here is a reference to the [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)

One thing to notice is that the return type has to be same.

So in your case you might want to create a new method rather than overriding the method.

There is no return type covariance in C#

Comment: He wants the method to return ```string``` instead of ```bool```, it's not possible.

Comment: @JOSEFtw I understand.  That is why I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to change the return type when overriding a method.
[C#: Overriding return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048884/c-overriding-return-types)

Microsoft has an open issue for it on GitHub though: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49

It's not marked for implementation/release anytime soon though.