# Why is covariance not working as expected?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Why is this not working? The compiler should be smart enough to know that InterfaceB requires InterfaceA and therefore must be compatible.

```
public interface InterfaceA
{ }

public interface InterfaceB : InterfaceA
{ }

public abstract class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override InterfaceB ItemService { get; set; } // Error, needs to be InterfaceA
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual InterfaceA ItemService { get; set; }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: you cannot change contract

Comment: also this doesn't make sens ... as with `BaseClass derived = new DerivedClass();` you can assign something which is not a `InterfaceB` like  `derived.ItemService= instanceOfImplementationOfInterfaceAAndNotInterfaceB;`

Comment: via the base class you can assign any interfaceA  to "ItemService" which may not implement interfaceB.....

Comment: The answer did not change since 2009 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048929/477420... And as @Selvin pointed out sample shown in the question does not makes sense - there is no way to change type of both get and set and support variance (either co- or contra-). You may have some ground to expect it working with *either* get or set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the base class says any InterfaceA can be assigined to ItemService, so a derived class can't change that to say "Only InterfaceB can be assigned to it".  But if you ditch the assignment,  so  it is  :-

```
  public interface InterfaceB : InterfaceA
    {
    }

    public abstract class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        protected override InterfaceB ItemService { get; } // no set
    }

    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        protected virtual InterfaceA ItemService { get; }

    }
```

it will work, as there is no assignment....but I'm not sure your actual goal

Comment: yes, as setting the variable can be done in different ways like overriding in derived class the get only property can still be set by the ctor, I go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> The compiler should be smart enough to know that InterfaceB requires InterfaceA and therefore must be compatible.

But it's not compatible - you could do this:

```
DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();
InterfaceB ib = new InterfaceBImpl(); 
derived.ItemService = ib;              // good so far
InterfaceA ia = new InterfaceAImpl();  // still good
BaseClass bc = derived;                // still a legal downcast
bc.ItemService = ia;                   // seemingly good - BaseClass can store an InterfaceA
ib = derived.ServiceImpl;
```

Here is where it blows up. You have stored an object that does not implement InterfaceB in a property that *should* require an `InterfaceB`.

One common way to do what you want is still generics:

```
public abstract class DerivedClass : BaseClass<InterfaceB>
{
    //protected override InterfaceB ItemService { get; set; } // Error, needs to be InterfaceA
    // no override needed - ItemService will now be of type InterfaceB
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : InterfaceA
{
    protected T ItemService { get; set; }
}
```

I'll admit that I haven't studied up on C# 9 much yet, but from what I see the covariant returns only apply to *methods* and *get-only* properties. If that were the case here, your solution would be fine. It's the *setter* that allows you to break the type system in this case.

It also seems that *read-only* properties are supported, so you may be able to do this:

```
public abstract class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override InterfaceB ItemService { get; } 
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual InterfaceA ItemService { get; }
}
```

Comment: "but from what I see the covariant returns only apply to methods."
Nope, works for both. Return type covariance only works for get only properties or methods, which makes sense. Covariance is only allowed for return only types. A setter violates this rule. Thanks for pointing this out.